# how to turn on performselectorinbackground functionality Ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying to use performselectorinbackground but it not running. some one told me that there is check in the application settings to allow background tasks in ios but i am unable to find that check. so please tell me how to turn on background task functionality by adding the check to the app settings plist file. I am using this code for background task.

```
@implementation NetworkHandler
@synthesize delegate=_delegate;

- (void)sendServerCall:(NSDictionary *)data {
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(onBackground:) withObject:data];
}

-(void)onBackground:(NSDictionary *)data
{
    @try{
        _methodNameResult=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [data objectForKey:Dictionary_Keys_Method],Dictionary_Keys_ResultVal];
        _delegateKey=[[data objectForKey:Dictionary_Keys_Delegate] integerValue];
        NSURL *serviceUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[data objectForKey:Dictionary_Keys_WebServiceUrl]];
        NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:serviceUrl];
        NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[[data objectForKey:Dictionary_Keys_SopaMessage] length]];
        [theRequest addValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [theRequest addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [data objectForKey:Dictionary_Keys_WebServiceNameSpace],[data objectForKey:Dictionary_Keys_Method]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
        [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [theRequest setHTTPBody:[[data objectForKey:Dictionary_Keys_SopaMessage] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self ];
        if ( theConnection ){
            _conWebData= [NSMutableData data];
        }
        else
        {
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(onMain:) withObject:[[NSDictionary alloc]init] waitUntilDone:true];
        }
    }@catch (NSException *exception) {
        [CommonMethods logException:@"NetworkHandler - onBackground\n" :exception :@"NetworkHandler"];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(onMain:) withObject:[[NSDictionary alloc]init] waitUntilDone:true];
    }
}

-(void)onMain:(NSDictionary *)data
{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(onMain:) withObject:[[NSDictionary alloc]init] waitUntilDone:true];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse*)response{
    @try{
        [_conWebData setLength:0];
    }@catch (NSException *exception) {
        [CommonMethods logException:@"NetworkHandler - didReceiveResponse\n" :exception :@"NetworkHandler"];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(onMain:) withObject:[[NSDictionary alloc]init] waitUntilDone:true];
    }
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data{
    @try{
        [_conWebData appendData:data];
    }@catch (NSException *exception) {
        [CommonMethods logException:@"NetworkHandler - didReceiveData\n" :exception :@"NetworkHandler"];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(onMain:) withObject:[[NSDictionary alloc]init] waitUntilDone:true];
    }
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didFailWithError:(NSError*)error{
    @try{
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(onMain:) withObject:[[NSDictionary alloc]init] waitUntilDone:true];
    }@catch (NSException *exception) {
        [CommonMethods logException:@"NetworkHandler - didFailWithError\n" :exception :@"NetworkHandler"];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(onMain:) withObject:[[NSDictionary alloc]init] waitUntilDone:true];
    }
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection{
    @try{
        NSString*theXML = [[NSString alloc]initWithBytes: [_conWebData mutableBytes]length:[_conWebData length]encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSError *parseError = nil;
        NSDictionary *data=[[NSDictionary alloc]init];
        data=[XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:theXML error:&parseError];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(onMain:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:true];
    }@catch (NSException *exception) {
        [CommonMethods logException:@"NetworkHandler - connectionDidFinishLoading\n" :exception :@"NetworkHandler"];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(onMain:) withObject:[[NSDictionary alloc]init] waitUntilDone:true];
    }
}
```

I dont know but I think I don not need to performSelectorInbackground here because i think i am performing server call here and  performSelectorInbackground is basically for internal calculations or used when fetching data from internal db so there is no need of using performSelectorInbackground but if other wise if i need to use performSelectorInbackground so what then how we can enable this feature aur it is automatically enabled???

Comment: Are you sure you are not confusing [background threads](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH15-SW13) and [background tasks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)?

Comment: I'm sure he is confusing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

performSelectorInBackground and performSelectorOnMainThread are related to performing operations(executing functions) on background and main thread respectively. Both these functions are related to threading concepts.

performSelectorInBackground, executes the instructions inside the selector on the background thread. And this works when the app is in foreground state.

If you want to execute any task when the app is in background state, than in that case performSelectorInBackground won't work.

If you want to execute tasks in background than following links could be useful-

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I was loking for this